# Processing avoid frame gray border if size() less than 130pixel?

Tags: processing

I have the requirement to build a sketch where the Frame is very width but have quite a compressed height, say for instance 1024x100 pixel dimension. However, any width or height less than 130pixel, do get a gray border.

For instance the following example:

```java
size(100,100);
background(#FF00FF);
```

you will have a 15pixel gray border all around the purple area of the sketch, as attached example.

Is there any way to avoid this, please?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service

Comment: @Mayankswami thank you anyway, and no I'm not asking for code writing service, I was asking if somebody knew where the issue was originating. It is originating in the 'PApplet' class, now I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.
The issue is originating in the `PApplet` which every sketch extends, and the minimum windows height and width are hardcoded to value 128.

The workaround I found was to continuously call `frame.setSize()` in the `draw()` method.

Alternatively another solution could be to extend `PApplet` methods to overcome the hardcoding, but for me it worked very well the previously mentioned workaround.